# Android | GLESv2 "error: undefined reference to 'glColor4f'"

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I working on `NativeActivity` android application that use OpenGL ES 2.0

When I build my app with `-lGLESv2` I got linker error

> error: undefined reference to 'glColor4f'

All another OpenGL ES founded.

But when I replace `-lGLESv2` with `-lGLESv1_CM` (or just add `-lGLESv1_CM`) all is ok

My question is it this correct solution of my problem? Can I use simultaneously `-lGLESv2` and `-lGLESv1_CM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't mix ES 1.x with ES 2.0. The are mostly incompatible, and not supported by the same context on any devices I have seen. You decide which one you use as part of the context creation, and then you have to stick with that version.

If you look at the [official spec file](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/doc/registry/public/api/gl.xml), ES 2.0 is defined as a new API, not as an updated version of ES 1.x. Their differences are much bigger than their similarities.

As you realized, `glColor4f()` is a ES 1.x function. The most common relative in ES 2.0 is `glVertexAttrib4f()`. Since color was a fixed function attribute, and the whole fixed function pipeline is gone in ES 2.0, it's not a direct replacement.